# JSON.NET cannot find assembley

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I made a project on vs2012 TFS on a machine and added Json.Net refrence by installing, but when I open the same project on another machine it says that the refrence was not found. Any suggestions to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are referencing it from the GAC. So: either install it on the second machine, or: don't use the GAC. This package is readily available in NuGet, which allows both local deploy or package restore - plus makes updating a breeze.

Comment: I am trying to install but it says that it has already a reference.

Comment: @MuneebZulfiqar you need to remove the old references first

Comment: I have already tried what you are saying mate. Its not helping